# Showing a function does not have a certain type of fixed point

Tags: complex-dynamics, fixed-points

> Suppose that $z_0$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is a fixed point of an analytic function of $F$.  Then $z_0$ is:
>    - Super-attracting if $f'(z_0)=0$
>    - Attracting if $0<|f'(z_0)|<1$
>    - Repelling if $|f'(z_0)|>1$
>    - Rationally indifferent if $f'(z_0)$ is a root of unity
>    - irrationally indifferent if $|f'(z_0)|=1$, but $f'(z_0)$ is not a root of unity

These are the two questions:

(a)  Show that $z \to z^2$ has no indifferent fixed points.
(b)  Show that $z\to z+z^2$ has no repelling fixed points.

I understand how to determine what fixed points these functions have, but I'm not sure how one would go about showing that a particular function does NOT have a certain type of fixed point.  My idea is below:

(a)  Suppose $f(z)=z^2$ had a rationally indifferent fixed point.  Then there exists a fixed point $z_0$ such that $z_0^2-z_0=0$ and $2z_0=e^{2\pi i k}$ or $z_0=\frac{e^{2pi i k}}{2}$.  I believe this shows that the fixed point would have to be $\frac{1}{2}$, which does not work.

(b)  Suppose it had a repelling fixed point.  Then there exists a $z_0$ such that $z_0^2+z_0=z_0$ and $|2z_0+1|>1$.  Eventually this shows that it has a large set fixed point, none of which actually work.

Am I on the right track with these problems?

Comment: In both cases you can *solve* the equation $f(z_0) = z_0$, and determine $f'(z0)$ at the (two) fixed points.

Comment: Correct.  But, for example,  I am trying to show it has no indifferent fixed points.  So I assume it has one and it fails.

Comment: Your problem is still unclear to me. For $f(z) = z^2$, $z_0=0$ and $z_1= 1$ are the *only* fixed points (and $\infty$ if you work on the extended complex plane). $z_0$ is superattracting and $z_1$ is repelling.

Comment: I just thought this problem may have an additional layer of complexity since its has "Show that"..."has no" instead of classify fixed points.